# href click problem if i add runat="server" attribute in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, href

here is one href on aspx page

**ASPX:**

```
<a id="hrfReport" href="<%=sApplicationURL%>Reports.aspx">Report</a>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
sApplicationURL = "http://localhost/";
```

now if i click on href page redirected to the reports page but if i add runat="server" attribute then href click not worked.actually i want to make it disable on particular condition.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `<%=someVal%>` construct in server tags.  The compiler basically translates that to `Response.Write(someVal)`.

You can use the `<%#someVal%>` construct, but you are required to `DataBind()` the value.  For example:

**ASPX:**

```
<a id="hrfReport" href='<%#sApplicationURL + "Reports.aspx"%>' runat="server">Report</a>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
sApplicationURL = "http://localhost/";
hrfReport.DataBind();
```

Alternatively...

If you have a server control, you can set its properties from the code behind as follows:

**ASPX:**

```
<a id="hrfReport" runat="server">Report</a>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
hrfReport.HRef = sApplicationURL + "Reports.aspx";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your ASPX page.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hrfReport" NavigateUrl="~/Reports.aspx" Text="Report"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the link and enable/disable it in the code behind:

```
Sub Page_Load()
  HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = sApplicationURL & "Reports.aspx"
  HyperLink1.Enabled = "false"
End Sub
```

Then just add your link on the page:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Report</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the HyperLink control, you can use a href:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="lnkLogout" onserverclick="lnkLogout_Click"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub lnkLogout_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkLogout.DataBinding
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon()
    Try
        Response.Redirect("../Login/login.aspx")
    Catch ex1 As ThreadAbortException
        Thread.ResetAbort()
    End Try
End Sub
```